# LLVM IR get a pointer from a llvalue

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm working with the LLVM IR in Ocaml to build a toy language and, now my problem is to convert the variable into the reference to this variable.

In other words, my simple program is this

```c
int main(){
  int i;
  i = 2;
  int *p;
  p = &i;
  print(*p);
  return 0;
}
```

and my problem is to get the pointer of the variable `i` in the instruction `p = &i;`, my actual
IR generated is

```
define i32 @main() {
entry:
    %i = alloca i32
    store i32 2, i32* %i
    %p = alloca i32*
    %0 = getelementptr i32, i32* %i, i32 0
    store i32* %0, i32** %p
    %1 = load i32*, i32** %p
    %2 = load i32, i32* %1
    call void @print(i32 %2)
    ret i32 0
}
```

I don't like this line `%0 = getelementptr i32, i32* %i, i32 0`, and I think that I'm only lucky that my code work as expected.

To summarize my question is, What is the good practice to make this memory operation with a variable like C language? In particular, I need to to the following

```c
i = 2;
int *p;
p = &i;
```

And also

```c
int *p;
p = &i;
*p = *p + 2;
```

I'm missing something because when I try to compile code like that `*p = *p + 2;` I receive some core dump.

I noted also that clang for my first example doesn't use `getelementptr`, but generate some code like that

```
; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
    %1 = alloca i32, align 4
    %2 = alloca i32, align 4
    %3 = alloca i32*, align 8
    store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
    store i32 2, i32* %2, align 4
    store i32* %2, i32** %3, align 8
    %4 = load i32*, i32** %3, align 8
    %5 = load i32, i32* %4, align 4
    %6 = call i32 (i32, ...) bitcast (i32 (...)* @print to i32 (i32, ...)*)(i32 %5)
    ret i32 0
}
```

In my grammar, the `*p` is a pointer and I convert it into llvm IR into an llvm pointer type.

Comment: Indeed, why do you use GEP at all? You can store `i32* %i` into `i32** %p` right away.

Comment: I can not ask to "Why", because in my mind some point I said, ok  I need a pointer and I the GEP operation give me the location of this variable, for this reason, I use it

Comment: @arrowd, and to make the reverse operation? so get the variable from the pointer, the answer is LOAD again?

Comment: Usually the `i32* %i` is what you would attach to the name `i` in the symbol table, so you could just pass it to any pointer variable that wants it or any operation that changes `i`'s value

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo Right, `load` takes a value of `<type>*` and returns a value of `<type>`.